# Java Regex too greedy capturing groups

Tags: java, regex

```
    Node0x7fd34984d728:s1 -> Node0x7fd34984d600:d0;
    Node0x7fd34984d850 [shape=record,shape=Mrecord,label="{Register %vreg13|0x7fd34984d850|{<d0>i32}}"];
    Node0x7fd34984d978 [shape=record,shape=Mrecord,label="{{<s0>0|<s1>1}|CopyFromReg [ORD=1]|0x7fd34984d978|{<d0>i32|<d1>ch}}"];
    Node0x7fd34984d978:s0 -> Node0x7fd3486095f0:d0[color=blue,style=dashed];
    Node0x7fd34984d978:s1 -> Node0x7fd34984d850:d0;
    Node0x7fd34984daa0 [shape=record,shape=Mrecord,label="{Register %vreg14|0x7fd34984daa0|{<d0>i32}}"];
```

I'm trying to capture only Nodes with "ORD" keyword, my simple Regex pattern is:

```
Node.+?label=\"\\{\\{(?<SRC><s[0-9]+?>[a-z0-9]+?)\\}|(?<NAME>.+?)\\[ORD=(?<ORD>[0-9]+?)\\]\\|(?<ID>[A-Za-z0-9]{14})|\\{(?<DEST><d[0-9]+?>[a-z0-9]+?)\\}\\}\"\\];
```

*It's too greedy capturing wrong groups.*

The following snippet is captured as one group!

```
Node0x7fd34984d728:s1 -> Node0x7fd34984d600:d0;
Node0x7fd34984d850 [shape=record,shape=Mrecord,label="{Register %vreg13|0x7fd34984d850|{<d0>i32}}"];
Node0x7fd34984d978 [shape=record,shape=Mrecord,label="{{<s0>0|<s1>1}|CopyFromReg [ORD=1]|0x7fd34984d978|{<d0>i32|<d1>ch}}"];
```

However it must only capture:

```
Node0x7fd34984d978 [shape=record,shape=Mrecord,label="{{<s0>0|<s1>1}|CopyFromReg [ORD=1]|0x7fd34984d978|{<d0>i32|<d1>ch}}"];
```

as it's the only **Node** has "**ORD**" keyword before **Semicolon**

Comment: `SRC`,`NAME`,`ID`,`DEST` and `ORD` are my 5 capturing groups names.

Comment: What should go into these groups? See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hN8zM3/1). It is rather strange you chose alternation groups rather than optional groups.

Comment: Looks good, are you sure the regexp you posted here is the same one you are having problems with?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `SRC=<s0>0|<s1>1`, `NAME=CopyFromReg `, `ID=0x7fd34984d978`, `DEST=<d0>i32|<d1>ch`, `ORD=1`

Comment: Are you using DOTALL mode?

Comment: @JulienCharon I didn't set a mode! my text may be stream without any `\s`'s

Comment: Check this: [`Node[^\\]\\[]*\\[[^\\]\\[]*label=\"\\{\{(?<SRC>[^{}]*)\\}\\|(?<NAME>\\w+)\\s*\\[ORD=(?<ORD>\\d+)\\]\\|(?<ID>[^|]*)\\|\\{(?<DEST>[^{}]*)\\}\\}\"\\];`](https://regex101.com/r/zH6oA1/2).

Comment: Are there new lines separating the lines the way you posted, or is it just a semicolon?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks :)

Comment: j@user1803551 semicolons

Comment: does it mean my regex is working for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get rid of any lazy and dot matching patterns and replace them with negated character classes. That way, you will prevent "overflowing" between parts of your substrings.

```
String pattern = "Node[^\\]\\[]*\\[[^\\]\\[]*label=\"\\{\{(?<SRC>[^{}]*)\\}\\|(?<NAME>\\w+)\\s*\\[ORD=(?<OR‌​D>\\d+)\\]\\|(?<ID>[^|]*)\\|\\{(?<DEST>[^{}]*)\\}\\}\"\\];";
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zH6oA1/2)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to not use one monster pattern but two simple patterns to extract what you want
use this pattern first:

```
^Node.*?label="{(.*\bORD\b.*)}".*?;
```

to extract "only Node has "ORD" keyword before Semicolon"
`{<s0>0|<s1>1}|CopyFromReg [ORD=1]|0x7fd34984d978|{<d0>i32|<d1>ch}`
[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/340)

then use this pattern

```
({.+?}|[^\|]+(?=\[ORD=\d+\])|[^\|]+)
```

for your various capturing groups - they are numbered not named though.
[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oM9wJ5/1)
results :

> MATCH 1
>   `{<s0>0|<s1>1}`
>   MATCH 2
>   `CopyFromReg`
>   MATCH 3
>   `[ORD=1]`
>   MATCH 4
>   `0x7fd34984d978`
>   MATCH 5
>   `{<d0>i32|<d1>ch}`